# Why was the subject and verb inverted in a declarative sentence?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion, syntactic-analysis, eighteenth-century-english

Preface: I ask only about the syntax and not semantics; I comprehend the meaning behind the following quote (for a paraphrase in 20C English; see [p 27](http://www.earlymoderntexts.com/assets/pdfs/hume1748_3.pdf) of 35), but I am inexperienced with Early Modern English syntax.

<sub>[Source:](http://18th.eserver.org/hume-enquiry.html) Section 12, Part 1, *An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding* (1748) by D Hume</sub>

> There is a species of scepticism, antecedent to all study and philosophy, which is much inculcated by Des Cartes and others, as a sovereign preservative against error and precipitate judgement. It recommends an universal doubt, not only of all our former opinions and principles, but also of our very faculties; of whose veracity, say they, we must assure ourselves, by a chain of reasoning, deduced from some original principle, which cannot possibly be fallacious or deceitful. But **neither** is there any such original principle, which has a prerogative above others, that are self-evident and convincing: or if there were, **could we** advance a step beyond it, but by the use of those very faculties, of which we are supposed to be already diffident. The Cartesian doubt, therefore, were it ever possible to be attained by any human creature (as it plainly is not) would be entirely incurable; and no reasoning could ever bring us to a state of assurance and conviction upon any subject.

Please see the bold above: Why might have Hume inverted the subject and modal auxiliary verb?

My conjecture: Is that declarative statement (with the bolded) meant as a rhetorical question? I am unsure because if so, would Hume have concluded it with a question mark?

<sub>PS: Initially I did not notice the significance of 'neither', but the comments and answer have since motivated me to bold it.</sub>

Comment: **"Neither is there...nor could there be"** is a common parallel construction. The "neither" matters. But for the actual answer from the horse's mouth, ask Hume, wherever he is, or might, or could be, were he still being, to be, or was, or shall be... huh?

Comment: We have to bear in mind this text is very, *very, **very*** old. I don't think it's a rhetorical question though. Consider how it looks if you discard a wodge of preceding text: *But **neither ... could we** advance a step beyond it, but (except) by the use of those very faculties*. That seems a reasonable parsing to me.

Comment: It's not a rhetorical question. It's a negative statement ... there's an implicit *neither* or *nor* before ***could we***, as I was about to say when two other comments beat me to it.

Comment: @Peter Actually, the *neither* is there, the second word in the sentence, and *or* is used in the place of *nor*. *Neither ... or* is fairly common well into the 19th century. See [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed6barch#page/n919/mode/2up), **A.1.e.**

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, come! This is hardly even *very* old, as far as the language goes, though the thought is pretty dated.

Comment: @StoneyB - I really like it when you answer and comment. You make this a much better place.

Comment: @StoneyB: I think the phrasing is quite "circumlocutory / verbose" compared to what we'd normally expect today. And despite what medica and Peter have said, I don't really see a simple *neither...nor* construction here. What ***I*** see is a quite "nice" little twist following the semicolon, where using ***or*** instead of ***nor*** subtly coerces the following text into something more akin to an "aside", rather than a simple continuation of the statement.

Comment: @medica You could not love me, Dear, so much Loved you not Grammar more.

Comment: I read it as follows: *[W]e could not possibly be fallacious or deceitful, but neither is their any such principle, or if there were, (neither) could we advance a step beyond it.* I don't see it as an implied *nor* but an extension of the prior *neither.* The *neither* refers antecedently and isn't propagating a *nor*.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman It is not we but the original principle which must not be "fallacious or deceitful". It's a slam against the cogito.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Pshaw! You only say that because you are thinking of quite different sorts of text. Spend an hour reading Derrida or Merleau-Ponty or any of the contemporary Higher Incomprehensibilities, and you will return to Locke as to a breath of colloquial fresh air.

Comment: @StoneyB: Do keep up! We're discussing *Hume*, not ***Locke**!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers <blush>. <But here's a little M-P> I am, not a ‘living creature’ nor even a ‘man’, nor again even ‘a consciousness’ endowed with all the characteristics which zoology, social anatomy or inductive psychology recognize in those various products of the natural or historical process—I am the absolute source, my existence does not stem from my antecedents, from my physical and social environment; instead it moves out towards them and sustains them, for I alone bring into myself (and therefore into being in the only sense that the word can have for me) [*continued*]

Comment: the tradition which I elect to carry on, or the horizon whose distance from me would be abolished—since that distance is not one of its properties—if I were not there to scan it with my gaze.

Comment: @StoneyB: Eeek! I'd probably do better reading that in the French original!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in StoneyB's answer, the construction *neither .... or* was previously an alternative to modern day *neither ... nor*. As such the *or* represents a negative word that has been fronted to the beginning of the second clause. The complicating factor, which makes it difficult to see why the negation is required here, is the intervening conditional protasis *if there were*. If we move that to the end of the clause it will be easier to intuitively understand why the second inversion is required:

> But **neither** is there any such original principle ... [**n**]**or** could we advance a step beyond it ... if there were.

Answer (score 2):

*Neither .. or* is used here where PDE demands *neither .. nor*. Both constructions demand inversion:

> But **neither** is there any such original principle [...] [n]**or** if there were could we advance a step beyond it ...

Comment: Thanks as always. Please allow me to postpone acceptance to allow time for (changes to) answers.

Comment: I think we might be getting down to the level of nit-picking, besides which I'm not really qualified to opine on exactly what constructions were "normal" in this kind of text almost three centuries ago. So I can only really parse the text using my *modern* ear. But it seems possible to me the emphasis might fall on *But neither **is** there any such original principle* (as the one which was "hypothetically" postulated in the preceding sentence). So the negation implied by *neither* actually applies *back* to a previous (but refuted) conjecture, not forward (to another reason to reject things).

Comment: @FumbleFingers : That's what I said.  Whew.  I felt like I was hanging onto the end of a limb there for a bit.  BTW, StoneyB, I too didn't leave a real answer, just my mewling with cowardace answer in comments, because I too do not really feel qualified to opine on exactly what constructions were normal in this kind of text almost three centuries ago.  Hell, I'm lucky if I can read Kerouac or Salinger without scratching my head.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But the assertion of the prior proposition is **not** refuted until DH says "There's no such thing". *Descartes and his cronies assert that we must doubt our faculties until we can legitimate them by deduction from an infallible principle. But there's no such principle; and even if there were such a thing, the only way we could deduce anything from it is by using the very faculties we're supposed to be doubting.*

Comment: I will cross neither words nor swords with you at that level (a wise man knows when he's licked! :) I recall that yesterday I was only really trying to express a degree of support for a comment by @Benjamin that seems to have been tidied away now. But in the cold (and it really *is*) light of this afternoon (and your paraphrasing), I see it really is essentially a *neither / nor* - and I'm sure you're right that *at the time* it was okay to use *neither / **or*** in such contexts.